# Why are array offsets considered own properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, serialization

In my serialization code, I stumbled across a a stinky issue - as I loop through generic object properties, it also serializes array indexes, which is really not the plan - I serialize this data later on without saving the indexes in the stream.

```
[1].hasOwnProperty("0") // true
```

So my question is, why are array indexes considered own properties by the `hasOwnProperty` method? Is there even a way to **tell property from array offset**? A **generic** way that also works for `TypedArray`, `HTMLElementCollection` and whatever else?

Of course, this can be done, but it stinks:

```
  for(var i in this) {
    if(this.hasOwnProperty(i) &&
      // If object is an array, we ignore the number offsets as they're not meant to be object properties
      (typeof this.length!="number" || !(i<this.length) || i.length==0)) {
```

And yeah, the `i.length==0` is there because you can actually do this:

```
var obj = {};
obj[""] = "something";
console.log(obj);
```

[image: image description]

Yeah, you're welcome, enjoy your nightmares.

Comment: You already have your answer, but again: Arrays are objects. Array elements are properties of the array object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are objects, just slightly specialised. And as you have discovered, the indexes of an array are just properties called 0, 1, 2 etc.

On a really simple level, the length property just finds the highest numeric property and adds one.

You could make a slightly simpler way of filtering the keys, along the lines of

```
for (key in obj) {
    if (isNaN(+key) && obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        doSomething()
    }
}
```

Depends if you want to include the numeric properties of objects. It would be perfectly valid to do `a = {'0': 'value'}`, which is for the purpose of this exercise the same as `b = ['value']`. Although `b` has a length property and `a` does not, also `b` has all the other functions that come from being an array.

Comment: In practice, odds of object that have numeric-only properties are low. But I was more about the way it actually works - I think arrays are somewhat different than other objects - eg. setting numeric property to an array will fill array with `undefined` all the way up to the number you've set. (`[]["666"]="big number"` creates 667 items long array) So they are not behaving as normal properties. I was hoping there would be a way to detect that.

Comment: As I said, I think the way to do it is just see if the properties are numeric, thats what `isNaN(+key)` does. Maybe you just need to do `Array.isArray(obj)`?

In terms of filling up, really thats down to the implementation - I know that V8 will treat an array with gaps, just the same as it does and object - in terms of how it is stored in memory. Just because the debugger shows you 665 `undefined`s - thats the same as if they where not there. Try this 'a = []; a[100] = 1;for (key in a) console.log(key)` - prints only `100`

Comment: @TomášZato: *"setting numeric property to an array will fill array with `undefined` all the way up to the number you've set."* Uhm, no, not all. Look at this: `var arr = []; arr[100] = 42; console.dir(arr);`. You won't see any indexes with `undefined`. *"I think arrays are somewhat different than other objects"* Well, they have special internal behavior, just like functions, but they are still objects at the end of the day.

Comment: @FelixKling Try to query for array length. It gives you 101, meaning all for loops are gonna go crazy. Surprisingly enough, `forEach` and the likes do not get confused by this.

Comment: @TomášZato As I said, length basically just gives you the highest numeric property + 1. It doesn't necessarily relate to the number of entries or the amount of memory used.

Comment: @TomášZato: *"It gives you 101, meaning all for loops are gonna go crazy."* That's how it is with sparse arrays. Presumably whoever does this has a reason for it. But the array is not filled with `undefined` values, like you were implying. That's how objects work. `var obj = {}; obj.length = 100; for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { console.log(obj[i]); }` gives you exactly the same result.

Comment: @TomášZato: `forEach` is explicitly defined to skip holes. You can read the spec if you like: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach .